# Checkbox value in controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, checkbox, view, controller

I am trying to get all the payments that is been selected through the checkboxes and then update the value in the database by '1' which means its paid. But when I try to get the values of checkbox array I only get 1 data in the array and not all selected. Any help?

***View***

```
@foreach($sellerID as $p)
   <form action="/paid/{{$p->id}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
        @csrf
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="{{ $p->id }}"></td>
     <td> {{$p->order_number}} </td>
     <td>
         <input id="commission" type="text" class="form-control" name="commission" 
         value="{{ $p->commission_value }}" readonly  autocomplete="notes" style="width: 15%;" autofocus>
     </td>
                                        
     <td> {{$p->product_name}} </td>
     <td> 
         @if($p->sellet_commission_paid == '0')
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:red">
                <b><em>UNPAID</b></em>
            </button>
         @else
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:green"><b><em>PAID</b></em></a>
         @endif                                    
     <td>   
  </form>
@endforeach
```

***Controller***

```
$checked = $request->input('checked');
     //   $checkboxes = $request->checked;

   dd($checked);
   die();
    //    dd(checkboxes);
```

Comment: But, you have only one checkbox here, thats why you get one

Comment: that's within the form for every result. should I place next to commission value?]

Comment: You need to put all input element  inside form :

Comment: every element is within the form. There is none out of the form

Comment: seems like you use more than one `<form>`, I answered with details.

Comment: I have only used one `<form>` tab

Comment: but there is only checkbox in your form

Comment: in my view I can see the checkboxes along with every payment so how will I get checkboxes with every payment if there is only one checkbox in my form?

Comment: But You posted only one checkbox element. Even there is no foreach loop.

Comment: I have updated the code. There was `foreach` loop but I didnt write here in the code

Comment: how can I add multiple checkboxes then?

Comment: please help me with this

Comment: You have a `form` inside a foreach, then you have multiple form element,  which have different route. And your `checkbox` are only one in a form element. Note : every form has different route. So when you submit,  only its input field you will get.,Not others

Comment: On your browser, if you hit `CTRL + U` and you will see multiple form element

Comment: its showing `paid/4` in the form value so its not taking all the checked value. How can I fix this? what do you suggest?

Comment: I dont know how do you send variable on this page. If `checked` is an array, then you need to another foreach loop to get it's data.

Comment: that checked is an array `<input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="{{ $p->id }}"`

Comment: `checked` should be an array. `$p->id` is a variable

Comment: I am just passing the values to checkbox array

Comment: What the variable name of the array?

Comment: its `checked[]`

Comment: `name="checked[]"` is the name

Comment: `$p->checked`??

Comment: `{{ $p->id }}` is the value that I am passing to `checked`

Answer (score 0):

you can put almost anything you like inside a form, but not inside a table. table has a more restricted structure which you must follow.

instead of wrapping table rows with forms, you can wrap the whole table with 1 form and submit all of it and just extract the details you need,

You need to put all input element  inside form  :

```
<form action="/route">
   <input ...../>
   <div>
      <input ...../>
   </div>
</form>
```

> A form-associated element is, by default, associated with its ancestor form element, but may have a form attribute specified to override this.

> If a form-associated element has a form attribute specified, then that attribute's value must be the ID of a form element in the element's owner Document.

Comment: do you mean that I need to separate the table with the form?

Comment: even I removed the table its giving the same result of returning only one item in an array

Comment: you have added the button outside the `<form>` how is that going to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a foreach loop.

```
foreach($request->input('checked') as $check){
  [sample variable] = $check;
 }
```

The array will now be stored as $check and you should be able to get each value from the input